# Text in flex item must wrap, not shift sibling and expand container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to fix the position of a flex container that contains two items: a yellow circle and some text.

When I add more text to the `p` element, the yellow circle shifts to the left. But I need the circle to hold its position. The text element should not expand; it should wrap.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 14%;
  top: 15%;
}
.flex .item {
  position: relative;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.flex .item span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 25px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.flex p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">
    <span>9</span>
  </div>
  <p>Text here</p>
</div>
```

Here's a [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/WoOMYB?editors=1100).

Comment: Do you want the text under the number?

Comment: No, I need if type more text, they shouldn't shift the yellow circle and text should wrap to a new line. But not under the number.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Volcan3/pen/rWwdVW something like this?

Comment: if the flex is absolute, i guess no needs for the children and so flex is avalaible. you still need to set a width to the parent : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qqjodV?editors=1100 if you want absolute children, then display comes useless :(

Comment: also need add word-wrap: break-word; for p tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things missing in your code that can make the layout work:

**1. Set a width on the container**

Since your container doesn't have a defined width, it will take the width of its content. Like this:

[image]

That's the problem you're having.

As shown in the image, the text doesn't wrap because it doesn't need to – there is no width constraint on the container, so it expands to accommodate longer content.

Add this to your code:

```
.flex { width: 150px; }
```

Now you have this:

[image]

**2. Disable `flex-shrink`**

[An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-shrink: 1`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-shrink-property). This means that flex items will shrink in order to fit inside the container (preventing overflow).

You can see the result of `flex-shrink` on the yellow circle in the image above.

You need to disable `flex-shrink`. Add this to your code:

```
.flex .item {
  position: relative;
  /* width: 5rem;        <-- remove this; not necessary */
  height: 5rem;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 5rem; /* flex-grow:0 (don't grow), flex-shrink:0 (don't shrink), width:5rem */
}
```

And now you have this:

[image]

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 14%;
  top: 15%;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.flex .item {
  position: relative;
  /* width: 5rem; */
  height: 5rem;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 5rem; /* NEW */
}
.flex .item span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 25px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.flex p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">
    <span>9</span>
  </div>
  <p>text here text here text here text here </p>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbLaqg)